# Laravel hasMany and belongsTo parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table store, and store has many libraries, in library I have foreign key of store `store_id`.

Store table

```
id(PK)
```

Library table

```
id(PK)
store_id(FK)
```

I'm confused with `hasMany` and `belongsTo` parameters include, in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) it says

> return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key');
>
> return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
>
> return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');

Which table of hasMany foreign_key and local_key came from? Same with belongsTo which table of foreign_key and other_key came from?

Store model

```
public function library(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Library', 'what_foreign_key_should_be_here','what_other_key_should_be_here');
}
```

Library model

```
public function stores(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Stores', 'what_foreign_key_should_be_here', 'what_other_key_should_be_here');
}
```

Because sometimes I change my primary key id of a table to other name like sid, so I always want to specify which is foreign key and primary key

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To simplify the syntax, think of the `return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` parameters as:

1. The model you want to link to
2. The column of the foreign table (the table you are linking to) that links back to the `id` column of the current table (unless you are specifying the third parameter, in which case it will use that)
3. The column of the current table that should be used - i.e if you don't want the foreign key of the other table to link to the `id` column of the current table

In your circumstance, because you have used `store_id` in the `libraries` table, you've made life easy for yourself. The below should work perfectly when defined in your `Store` model:

```
public function libraries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Library');
}
```

Behind the scenes, Laravel will automatically link the `id` column of the `Store` table to the `store_id` column of the `Library` table.

If you wanted to explicitly define it, then you would do it like this:

```
public function libraries(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Library', 'store_id','id');
}
```

- A model standard is that singularly-named functions return a belongsTo, while a plural function returns a hasMany (ie. `$store->libraries() or $library->store()`).

Answer (score 15):

Try this one. It works. Add this to your model.

**Library model**

```
public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'store_id', 'id');
    }
```

**Store model**

```
 public function libraries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Library::class);
    }
```

**example code.**

```
 $store = Store::find(1);
 dd($store->libraries);
```

Because in this case a store has many libraries, the `Store` model has a `libraries()` function. Refer to last line of [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841228/6053548) for more information on this standard.

Answer (score 2):

**Store table:**

```
store_id (PK)
```

**Library table:**

```
library_id (PK) 
library_fk_store_id (FK)
```

**Store model:**

```
public function libraries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Library::class, 'library_fk_store_id','library_id');
}
```

**Library model:**

```
public function store()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'library_fk_store_id', 'store_id');
}
```

- Foreign keys are **identical** in both methods:

```
`library_fk_store_id`
```

- Local/Owner keys are the ids from the **opposite** model/table:

```
`Store model -> library_id`
`Library model -> store_id`
```

- Local/Owner keys has the **same** name from the method names:

```
`libraries() -> library_id`
`store() -> store_id`
```