# Laravel: Query Builder creates plural name: columns_id instead of column_id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have my class "Product_reviews", which is binded to the class "Products" like this:

**Products.php:**

```
public function product_reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product_reviews');
}
```

**Product_reviews.php:**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Products');
}
```

Foreign key for table "Product_reviews" is 'product_id'.

So, in the controller I'm trying to get all data:

```
$products = Products::with('product_reviews')->get();
```

And... I have an error saying that product_id can't be found:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_reviews.products_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `product_reviews` where `product_reviews`.`products_id` in (1, 2))
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the query builder is adding '_id' to the class' name. It can be fixed by going to the table "product_reviews" and changing 'product_id' by 'products_id'... Or maybe I could pass all classes' and tables' names to singular.

So my question is: What other options do I have in order to make the query builder know the proper column's name?

Comment: because your model name is `Products`. Make it singular and problem must be solve

Comment: In the long run, you'd better rename your files and rewrite your models so that Model is singular. This helps Laravel's many naming assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your models should be named in the singular form, and then Laravel will not attempt to use the plural form of the column name in the generated SQL query.

In your case, the `Products` model should be called `Product`. Remember that a model represents **one** record in your database, so the singular form is correct.

You overwrote this behaviour by manually setting the foreign field in your `$this->hasMany(..)` relationship, which skirted around the issue, but didn't fix the underlying cause.

Additionally, you should avoid using snake_cased class names, as it violates PSR. Your `Product_reviews` model should be called `ProductReview`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it:

In **Products.php:**

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Product_reviews');
```

I added 2 more parameters to the function hasMany, like this:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Product_reviews','product_id','id');
```

These parameters specify the id's names.

This post really helped:

[laravel-hasmany-and-belongsto-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841159/laravel-hasmany-and-belongsto-parameters)

Anyhow I think it may be good in long terms to do what Davit and hktang say and rename my classes with singular names. Thanks for your answers.