# How do I get users last message using hasMany with laravel

Tags: laravel, relational-database

Message Tables Column is

```
| messages_id(pk) | user_id | target_id | message | created_at
```

User_id has sender user's id.   Target_id has receiver user's id

And simple user table has relation to MessageTable by HasMany.

```
public function message()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Model\TableModel\Message', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

I want to get Userdata and each last message from user_id=[1,2,3,4] to target_id = 5.

So I tried this

```
User::WhereIn(user_id, [1,2,3,4])
     ->with(['message' => function ($query) {
          $query->Where('target_id', 5)->orderBy('messages_id', 'desc)->first();
        }])->get();
```

But this query return User's data and one user last message.

How do I get users last message using hasMany ?

Comment: [This may give you some idea how to implement hasMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841159/laravel-hasmany-and-belongsto-parameters)

Comment: What's wrong with syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#has-many-relationships) relation is incorrect:
the third argument should be the primary key of the current model:

```
public function message()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Model\TableModel\Message', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

anyway, to get the last message, I recommend building a new relation using hasOne relation:

```
 public function lastMessage()
    {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Model\TableModel\Message', 'user_id', 'id')->latest();
    }
```

now, you can use this new relation like:

```
User::WhereIn(user_id, [1,2,3,4])
     ->with(['lastMessage' => function ($query) {
          $query->Where('target_id', 5);
        }])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you hero. latest method is what I looking for.